# PostgreSQL - create index is run before update is finished

Tags: json, postgresql

So I'm doing this update of legacy records to create valid objects.

```
-- just add legacy property with old record
UPDATE temp.log 
  set info = concat('{"legacy":', to_json(info), '}')
  where info not like '{%';

-- create index for new records with a json property
CREATE INDEX log_info_uid_idx ON temp.log((info::json->>'userId'));
```

The problem is that `CREATE INDEX` actually starts running before(!) the update would finish. Sometimes. For large logs. Normally I use JDBC, but same happens when testing in pgAdmin. Is there any way to be sure the index is created after the update?

The table is something like below and can have many (~million records):

```
CREATE TABLE temp.log
(
    id bigint NOT NULL,
    action_type character varying(255),
    date_modified timestamp without time zone,
    info text,
    CONSTRAINT log_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Some of the records in info have an object/JSON (something like: `{"userId":123,"foo":"bar"}`).
Legacy records don't have  a valid JSON (e.g.: `abc,123`).

PS: Tested this in PG 9.3 and PG 10. Both versions seem to have the same behavior.

***Edit*. Here is an example** for which I can repeat the weird behavior:

```
set search_path = temp;

-- clear
/*
delete from log;
drop INDEX log_info_uid_idx;
*/

-- random data (semi-csv in info)
insert into log (id, action_type, date_modified, info)
select i
    ,md5(random()::text)
    ,now()
    ,concat('notjson,', md5(random()::text))
from generate_series(1, 1000000) s(i)
;

UPDATE log 
  set info = concat('{"legacy":', to_json(info), '}')
  where info not like '{%';

-- create index for new records with a json property
CREATE INDEX log_info_uid_idx ON log((info::json->>'userId'));
```

PPS: The full error message below. This only appear if you run update and create index together. If you wait until update is finished it will not occur!

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type json
DETAIL:  Token "notjson" is invalid.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: notjson...
SQL state: 22P02
```

Comment: That behavior doesn't make sense.  What makes you think that the index creation is starting before the update finishes?

Comment: @Jeremy I know it start before update because it fails with something like "invalid syntax for json". If I run the queries separately in pgAdmin (update, wait, create) it works fine.

Comment: Added example data. Believe me I wasted hours on this, I know it doesn't make much sense 

Comment: Indeed [this works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=3084f3997c1a978014092ad34499cd29) but [this does not](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=30dd088ea35fb7455f366804108abb45)  Postgres 13 shows the same behaviour. Sounds like some transaction/commit/visibility problem if DML and DDL are run as a single statement. I guess the workaround is to use an `executeUpdate()` to run the `DML` and a (separate) `execute()` to run the DML from within Java

Comment: If you include a `commit` in the "single statement" [it works as well](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=7ec824719a34a26c04c86772f8ccc7ab)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I actually used to run bot in separate `Statement.executeUpdate()`.

Comment: It seems like adding transaction around works fine :-) `being;update...;commit;create index`. Just to be sure I run this all in one `executeUpdate`. Just to be sure I don't get some weird concurrency again. Same works well for pgAdmin :-). Thanks.

Comment: On slower machine (and longer table) the transaction was not enough. Explicit locking would help, but ended up using CIC as suggested in accepted answer. An interesting article about CIC: https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/create-index-concurrently/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply committing between steps might work, but will not always be enough.

When you build an index, it needs to index all the rows that might be visible to anyone, even if they are no longer visible to the session building the index.  That means that if there is another session with a long-running snapshot which was taken before the UPDATE finished, then CREATE INDEX will need to index the old row versions as well as the current ones, because the other session could still see those values.  But of course the old row versions are of the wrong syntax.

If you change the CREATE INDEX to work CONCURRENTLY, a side effect of this is that it will force it to wait until any old snapshots go away, so it won't have to index those old values.

Comment: Hmm, but [this example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=30dd088ea35fb7455f366804108abb45) shows that this is independent of concurrent sessions  - everything happens within the same snapshot

Comment: In that case, the "other" session interfering with it is itself.

Comment: Hm.. So even using begin;commit failed in some case. So I guess what you say is true for PG SQL "CREATE INDEX will need to index the old row versions as well as the current ones"... It doesn't make any sense for me though. Why would I ever need to use an index on old data? I mean it's fine if index is not used until it is fully ready. Using half done index is weird for me.

Comment: Heh. Weird. This worked . What is counter intuitive is that `CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY` doesn't actually run in parallel as the name suggest... Or at least not as I expected it. It is "concurrent" in that you can do __other__ things concurrently. But effectively it waits for other transactions. And so effectively it will wait for update to finish.